# MongoDB C# Remove doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

i have this code for removing an item froma a mongofb collation

```
private MongoCollection<T> GetCollection()
    {
       connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";
       server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
       database = server.GetDatabase("CSCatalog"); 

        return database.GetCollection<T>("myCollectionName");
    }
public bool  Delete(T entity)
    {            
        var id = typeof(T).GetProperty("Id").GetValue(entity,null).ToString();            
        var query = Query.EQ("_id",id);
        var finded = GetCollection().Find(query); // return null
        var result= GetCollection().Remove(query, MongoDB.Driver.RemoveFlags.Single);  // no errors, but don't remove 

        return esito.Ok; //return true but donn't remove.


    }
```

the GetCollection() method retrive the right collection, i have tested it width debug. 
In the collection there is the item that i want remove, it have the same id that i have retrived in first line.

the entity have some fields and a Objectid filed called "Id"

Comment: What happens? "Does not work" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 6):

the type of _id you created is ObjectId class and you are trying to equate with string so its not able to remove. use

var queryId = new ObjectId(id);

Answer (score 1):

Your `finded` variable should not be `null` if the `.find()` has returned something from your database.  That it is null means that you have not found anything, and therefore nothing is to  be removed.

What it looks like is happening here is that you are querying on `_id` for the ObjectId, while you are storing that ObjectId in the database as `Id`.